# Column Finite Matrices as a Ring of Endomorphisms of right free Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

In this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring), the 5-th example claims the ring of endomorphisms of right $R$-module $M=\oplus_{i\in I}R$ is isomorphic to the Column Finite Matrices $\mathbb{CFM}_I(R)$; while the ring is isomorphic to Row Finite Matrices $\mathbb{RFM}_I(R)$ when regarding $M$ as a left $R$-module.

I want to understand how the right/left module assumptions change the column/row orientation in the claim. Is it because, when $M$ is seen as a right module, we have to multiply the matrix from right side of a row "vector" in $M$? And vice versa? But if that's the case, in the first case, it doesn't seem we need the matrices to be column finite, since there are only finitely many nonzeros in the direct sum (row "vector").

That's my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempted to let $\mathbb{CFM}_I(R)$ operate on the right side of row vectors from $\oplus_I R$ you would immediately be in trouble, because the image of an element of $\oplus_I R$ might not be in $\oplus_I R$.

I'm taking liberties below to describe it as if it is indexed with $\omega$ so that I can talk about "first  row"  and whatever, but the same argument holds without a well-ordered index set (it's just more obnoxious to write.)

For example, let the "first" row of your column finite matrix be all $1$'s, and the second row be all $1$'s and the rest of the entries are all $0$. Obviously column finite, yes?

If you multiply this on the right side of the vector $[1,1,0,0,\ldots]$ (zeros on the tail forever, that is) then the result is $[2,2,2,2,\ldots]$ ($2$'s forever) which is not in $\oplus_I R$.

But if you have these matrices operate on the left side of column vectors from $\oplus_I R$, you will see that it does not have this problem.

> You explained why "multiplying the column vectors on the left by ℂ() works", but not  how it relates to $$ being a right $$-module.

Well, technically you would be considering $\oplus_I R$ as a left $R$ module when using RFM matrices on the right.  This is to ensure the transformation stays $R$ linear. Of course, that only matters when $R$ isn't commutative.

This is the natural action of a matrix $E$ on a right of $M$ in a matrix equation:  $E(xr)=(Ex)r$. If instead you wanted "$Erx=Exr$" to turn out right $R$ linear, then in general you have no way to commute the $r$ to the right of the $x$. That isn't a problem when you do it on the other side.

And likewise, the natural action of a matrix on the right is paired with the module action on the left:

$(rx)E=r(xE)$

Comment: I was thinking the finiteness, be it row or column, must come from the fact the image can only have finitely many non-zeros. So my question really is, why should we automatically think of column vectors multiplied on the left by $\mathbb{CFM}_I(R)$, but not row vectors multiplied on the right by $\mathbb{CFM}_I(R)$?

Comment: @user760 Didn't I just explain exactly why that (operating on the right of row vectors) doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "......, but not row vectors multiplied on the right by $\mathbb{RFM}_I(R)$?".

Comment: You explained why "multiplying the column vectors on the left by $\mathbb{CFM}_I(R)$ works", but not how it relates to $M$ being a right $R$-module.

Comment: @user760 Transposing everything, RFM work on the right of row vectors works, and using them on the left of column vectors doesn't work. Everything is exactly the same, just transposed.

Comment: @user760 Expanded the solution a bit more to try to accomodate your further comment.

Comment: Ah I see! When a matrix is multiplied on one side, you then can only multiply the ring values on the other side! As you can't multiply things in between the vector and the matrix. Thanks!

Comment: @user760 "can't mulitply htings in between the vector and the matrix" well, you _can_ (because it's the same as multiplying it by $Id\cdot r$ where $Id$ is the identity matrix. The point is that the results won't be $R$ linear if you have a noncommutative ring.

Comment: @user760 For example, just make things really easy in the $1\times 1$ case with quaternions.  You have $M=R=M_1(\mathbb H)=\mathbb H$.  The assignment $x\mapsto \lambda x$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb H$ is right $\mathbb H$ linear. But it is not left $\mathbb H$ linear, because, set $\lambda= i$ and $x=j$ and $r=k$:  $\lambda(rx)=ikj=1$ and $r\lambda(x)=kij=-1$

Answer (score 0):

You can roughly think of the endormorphism of a *right* $R$-module $M$ as matrices working on $M$ through multiplication on the *left*.

Perhaps this can be made clear with an example. Consider $A=k[(X_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}]/(X_{0}X_{i}-X_{0})_{i\in\mathbb{N}},(X_{i}X_{j})_{i>0,j\geq 0}$. Multiplying from the *left* with $X_{0}$ is a morphism from $A$ to $A$ in the category of *right* $A$-modules. Indeed, for any $a,b\in A$ we have $X_{0}(ab)=(X_{0}a)b$.  This does not work if we consider $A$ as a left module over itself, for then we would need $X_{0}(ab)=a(X_{0}b)$ for all $a,b$.

If we take $1,X_{0},X_{1},...$ as a $k$-basis for $A$, then this left multiplication is represented by the matrix $$M_{X_{0}}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\1&0&1&1&1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$
which is column finite but not row finite. For example, the element $1+X_{0}+X_{2}$ should be mapped to $2X_{0}$. Indeed:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\1&0&1&1&1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\\0\\\vdots\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\\\vdots\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Can you please explain what $A$ is in more details? Sorry I'm a bit lost by that expression. Is $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ the generating set? If it is, what ring/field it is based on? k?

Comment: Do you mean $k\left[(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\right]$ quotient out relations $\left<(X_0X_i -X_0)_{i}, (X_iX_j)_{i,j}\right>$, where $k$ is a field/ring?

Comment: Yes, $k$ is a base field. I add infinitely many variables such that the product of two variables is $0$ unless the first one is $X_{0}$. In that case, the product is $X_{0}$ if the second variable is not $X_{0}$ and $0$ otherwise.  Many variations on the same theme can be thought up.